# how to check the UITextField input have uppercase inputs - ios

Tags: ios

how to check the UITextField input have uppercase inputs.

for example : input is Girija return TRUE. input is girija return false. input is giRija return TRUE.

Please guide me. THanks

Comment: you mean at least one character should be capital ?

Comment: Define "uppercase".  Do you mean only ASCII characters or others as well?

Comment: @mert @jeepston and @shanegao all have correct solutions that don't require looping. If you want to check the characters as they're typed, look at the `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`. Also see `textFieldShouldReturn`. This will allow you to perform the check when the Return key is pressed and to act on that before dimissing the keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

```
BOOL hasUpperChars = ![[inputTxt lowercaseString] isEqualToString:inputTxt];
```

Comment: By far the nicest solution

Answer (score 3):

```
return ([textfield.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet]].location != NSNotFound)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSCharacterSet *uppercaseSet = [NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet];
NSString *str = @"test String";
NSRange range = [str rangeOfCharacterFromSet:uppercaseSet];
```

Now, if range.location != NSNotFound, your string has at least one uppercase character.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
NSString *myStr = @"YouR sTring";  
int count=0;  
for (i = 0; i < [myStr length]; i++) {
    BOOL uppercaseFlag = [[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[myStr characterAtIndex:i]];
    if (uppercaseFlag == YES)
       count++;
}
```

if count is greater than 1, means it contains an Uppercase letter

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL isUppercase = [[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[s characterAtIndex:0]];
```

it will check the first char of your `NSString` if you want to check every char of your `NSString` run it in loop.